# Могу ли я в ручную задать и отправить headers?

Tags: javascript, php

У меня такая ошибка:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at ‘XXXX’ from origin ‘YYYY’ has been blocked by CORS policy: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource.

Могу ли я вручную через php настроить и отправить headers?

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь получить данные через AJAX с удалённого сервера, и у Вас нет к нему доступа , то ничего не получится... Почитайте про CORS.

Answer (score 2):

Да, с помощью функции [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php).

Она должна вызываться строго **до** передачи клиенту тела ответа (то есть, до какого-либо вывода через *echo*, *print*, *printf*, и т.д.).
Также можно использовать буферизацию вывода - см. в справке директиву конфигурации [`output_buffering`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering), и функции [`ob_start`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start), [`ob_end_flush`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-end-flush.php).

Comment: я через hls.js со своего сайта воспроизвожу трансляцию, при подключении к нему у меня отсутствует заголовок «Access-Control-Allow-Origin». Расширение для google chrome "Play HLS M3u8" использует тот же самый HLS.JS и  он получает заголовок «Access-Control-Allow-Origin».

Comment: @DimaBuljgo, На фоновые скрипты расширений, CORS не распространяется (она, и COR**B** - действуют только на контент-скрипты). Потому что у расширений нет origin.

Comment: Для того чтобы кроссдоменный запрос "работал", нужно больше, чем просто один заголовок добавить в ответ... и насколько помню, кроссдоменно можно передавать только текстовую инфу. Посмотри статьи о CORS на английском MDN - насколько помню, там было очень хорошо все описано.

Comment: И еще, у меня однажды была ситуация с axios, который делал странное с preflight'ами. Тогда я так и не разобрался, в итоге психанул и переписал на собственный хелпер с XMLHttpRequest под капотом - и все моментально заработало. В общем, попробуй тоже ради теста обычным родным дом-апи отправить запрос. Хотя по тексту ошибки в вопросе, похоже что и так через него пытаешься, но мало ли...